# Transforming tf.data.Dataset to tfds.data_source

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I currently have a dataset that has been loaded using

`(ds_train, ds_test, ds_val), ds_info = tfds.load('speech_commands', split=splits,  data_dir=Flags.data_dir, with_info=True)`

which has been mapped and manipulated a few times.

I'd like to use this in Pytorch as a pytorch dataset (with a dataloader) but that requires it to be subscriptable (with a `__getitem__`).

A way to do this is with a tensorflow data_source object as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/tfless_tfds).

However, this starts with a builder, while I already have something from `tfds.load` which has already called `builder.as_dataset` instead of `builder.as_data_source`

Is there any way to transform my current datasets `(ds_train, ds_test, ds_val)` into a data source for external use?

Another way I thought was possible is `tf.data.Dataset.as_numpy_iterator()` but again this returns a non-indexable iterator.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: You have to re-generate your data in a file format that supports random access.

`tfds.data_source` needs the [`array_record`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/core/FileFormat) data format because it supports random access. So you have to prepare your data using `file_format='array_record'`. When omitting `file_format`, it implicitly defaults to tfrecord, which is why you cannot benefit random access. To fix this:

```py
tfds.data_source(
  'speech_commands',
  split=splits,
  data_dir=Flags.data_dir,
  builder_kwargs={'file_format': 'array_record'},  # For random access
)
```

If the dataset already exists in `data_dir`, you have to remove it from `Flags.data_dir` to download and prepare it again with the right file format. Alternatively, you can download and prepare it in another `data_dir`.

`file_format` can be used with [`tfds.data_source`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/data_source) (as shown in the snippet above, this is the equivalent of tfds.load) or with [`tfds.builder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/builder) (`tfds.builder(..., file_format='array_record')`).